# How can I quickly rename thousands of files in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, csv

Is there any fast way how to rename thousands of files in a single directory? I need to rename files with the specific last 3 characters in a name of the file. For example "TEST-AB.CSV" should be renamed to "TEST.CD.CSV". So all files with last 3 characters in the name like "-AB" replace with ".CD" But if the "-AB" string is not at the end of the filename, the file shouldn't be renamed.

Thank you for your help.

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it:

```
$path = "c:\temp"
$counter = 0
Get-ChildItem $path | ? {$_.basename.EndsWith("-AB")}|%{$counter++;rename-item $_.fullname (($_.basename -replace '(.*)(-AB)$','$1.CB')+$_.extension)}
$counter
```

EDIT

Added a counter.

Comment: I'd probably go with a substring rather than a replace since the latter might replace multiple instances.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "substring rather then replace"? Could you please explain?

Comment: He is right, what he means is that -replace will replace all occurences of "-AB" and not just the last one.

Comment: So one way to fix my example is to use a regex that will match just the last occurence of '-AB'

Comment: Thank you both you guys. Would it be possible to add some kind of counter to display how many files were renamed?

Answer (score 0):

In batch/cmd (ie. not PowerShell) you could do it like this:

```
ren *-AB.* *.CD.*
```

But if you need to use PowerShell, Micky's answer will do it.

**Edit** The above syntax appears to be limited to *not* introducing a "." into the rename. So:

```
ren *-AB.* *-CD.*
```

Works, but:

```
ren *-AB.* *.CD.*
```

Doesn't. I'd recommend going with Micky's answer